# How to create offline .dic file for pocketsphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

How to create offline .dic file for pocketsphinx? I used to use http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html but it is not working. So I created .lm file

```
#!/bin/bash
text2wfreq < 1.txt | wfreq2vocab > 1.vocab
text2idngram -vocab 1.vocab -idngram 1.idngram < 1.txt
idngram2lm -vocab_type 0 -idngram 1.idngram -vocab 1.vocab -arpa 1.arpa
sphinx_lm_convert -i 1.arpa -o 1.lm.DMP
sphinx_lm_convert -i 1.lm.DMP -ifmt dmp -o 1.lm -ofmt arpa
```

and I tried to create .dic file using http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/web/Software/g2p.html but with no success. G2P was built but failed to convert words from my dictionary.

Comment: This website is for programming questions, it is better to ask cmusphinx-specific questions on CMUSphinx forums instead. In order to get help you need to provide more information what exactly did you try and what failed.